# Problem when generating a Bibtexkey for a website using Jabref

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jabref

I am trying to quote the following website using Jabref:
[here](http://www.cis.hut.fi/research/som_lvq_pak.shtml)

Since I don't know the author of the website, and the website does not really seem to have a title, I include the following BibTex-key:

```
@misc{,
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.cis.hut.fi/research/som_lvq_pak.shtml}},
  note = {Accessed: 2020-06-18},
}
```

So. I am not sure, if I should give the name of the key as well (before the first comma). I have tried either way and for some reason, the key is not generated when I click on "generate Bibtex key". It is the first time this has ever happenned to me. So, am I missing some crucial entry?

Ok, just figured out, it will work with the following:

```
@Misc{,
  institution = {Helsinki University of Technology, Laboratory of Computer and Information Science},
  url         = {http://www.cis.hut.fi/research/som_lvq_pak.shtml},
}
```

But even this will only then work when I add an author. I don't know the author however. Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: allright, I figured it out: I have to change it as given in my edit. But even then it only works when I add an author, whom I don't know. Damn it, this is ridiculous

Comment: Hi, default bibtex key is author and year. However, in jabref you can change and define a default key pattern or specify one for each entry type. You can also manually define a key for that entry